# Wrap all children if children can't be displayed side-by-side using CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to display multiple choice buttons side-by-side if its possible given the screen real estate, ie.
`MC1 MC2 MC3 MC4`

but if it isn't possible and at least one element has to wrap, they should ALL be wrapped

```
MC1  
MC2  
MC3  
MC4
```

instead of 
`MC1 MC2 MC3

MC4`

The reason I want this unusual behaviour: We often have a number of choices in our psychological surveys where it is important that the end points of a rating scale are visually distant from each other to emphasise that they are different ends of a scale. We prefer to have a horizontal layout where possible, but if the last element wraps, it means the two end points are close together.

The survey layout is fluid and of course the children's widths are unknown. The children usually contain just text. They may contain images, but if someone thinks a solution counting characters and using `width:32ex` is actually viable, that's better than nothing (ie JS reflows).

I know I could easily do this with JS, but I was wondering whether there is a trick I don't know about to do this only with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do with pure CSS is to use media queries to force the elements to be all on the same line when above a certain break point.

http://jsfiddle.net/FpuHc/1/

```
@media (min-width: 30em) {
    ul {
        display: table;
        padding: 0;
    }

    li {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}

<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is better as it [allows for variable widths](http://jsfiddle.net/qYWpD/) of the children. I may have to go with media queries and a number of fixed parent widths anyway to make it look good. Thanks! Will accept if no one comes up with a solution where both parent and children's width can be variable.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

There is another solution with text-align:justify; on the wrapper and display: inline-block for the Elements inside. Might be the best solution.

Cheers, 
Felix

---

If you don't want to use JS the answer is **Media Queries** :)

If your Children are the same in numbers then I would go for (if you have 4 Children)

```
radio-wrapper .children {
width: 25%;
float: left;
}
```

and add a media query that (for example) makes them align vertical when you reach 600px

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    radio-wrapper .children {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this isn't perfect, in that you are arbitrarily selecting at what point to change up the layout (and assigning a specific width to each child element)... but I don't believe there's any other way to do it. Perhaps with a bit more information about the content and what's being aimed for visually this could be improved.

Comment: This doesn't do it. I can only use it if the widths of the children aren't variable (i.e. fit to their content, different widths for siblings) AND known. How else would I know what value to choose for max-width in the media query?

Comment: Absolutely, It's a more static solution - apparently I skipped the part with the generic widths - sry.
The adapted script above that turns your childs into table elements is the best answer.